# Zenoss No space left on device Error

Tags: virtualization, zenoss

```
Site Error

An error was encountered while publishing this resource.


Sorry, a site error occurred.
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 231, in publish_module_standard
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 165, in publish
Module Zope2.App.startup, line 211, in __call__
Module Products.ZenUI3.browser, line 105, in __call__
Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 60, in __call__
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 115, in pt_render
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 620, in do_insertText_tal
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 203, in evaluateText
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 222, in _handleText
Module zope.component._api, line 174, in queryUtility
Module zope.component.registry, line 165, in queryUtility
Module ZODB.Connection, line 834, in setstate
Module ZODB.Connection, line 884, in _setstate
Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 815, in load
Module ZEO.cache, line 143, in call
Module ZEO.cache, line 607, in store
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Went in to check my server through zenoss today and it looks like somehow my server is full.
Which when i look at my server its only 85% full:

```
unclebob:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/unclebob--vg0-unclebob--root
                      1.9G  1.5G  335M  82% /
tmpfs                 471M     0  471M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  820K  9.2M   9% /dev
tmpfs                 471M     0  471M   0% /dev/shm
overflow              1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/hde1             942M   36M  859M   5% /boot

    unclebob:/tmp# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/unclebob--vg0-unclebob--root
                      121920   54844   67076   45% /
tmpfs                 120489       3  120486    1% /lib/init/rw
udev                  120489    1520  118969    2% /dev
tmpfs                 120489       1  120488    1% /dev/shm
overflow              120489      14  120475    1% /tmp
/dev/hde1              61312      33   61279    1% /boot
```

It looks like theres these two files: .ICE-unix/ .X11-unix/

They had been hidden. I'll remove those. Any idea upon what they maybe?

Any ideas on a fix? Probably has something to do with Zenoss

Comment: Alright it seems that my /tmp was full. So i cleaned that out. Now i get an error with:

 The server reported the following error: IOError [Errno 28] No space left on device  The system has encountered an error. Please reload the page.

Comment: It seems i can't clean out my /tmp, i completely deleted everything but its still showing up at 100%

Comment: Is it possible that there was a large file that's now been deleted from /tmp or somewhere else, that was locked by the zenoss process, and now it still sees it as full, as the file handle is still open.  Try restarting zenoss, and see if it's still a problem.

Comment: I am actually seeing that /tmp is full within df -h, but i'll try to reset zenoss. I am resetting my server.

Comment: restarting after cleaning up the /tmp folder fixed everything. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your /tmp drive is full, and your application probably receives uploaded files in /tmp before putting it wherever it really belongs.

The other possibility is that you have millions of itty bitty files and you've run out of inodes, you can see how many inodes you have left with `df -i`.  But it's almost certainly the fact that /tmp is full that is the problem.

Comment: updated and posted my df -i, it doesn't seem to fix it when i cleaned out my /tmp